# What is the type hint for a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Is it just `callable`? In the meantime I have been using `function` as my IDE regards `callable` as a `bool`.

```
def func(a: int, b: str, callback: ???)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, [`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) is the right hint for a callback.

Also see the [*Callable* section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#callable) of PEP 484:

> Frameworks expecting callback functions of specific signatures might be type hinted using `Callable[[Arg1Type, Arg2Type], ReturnType]`.